# Reinstall Windows 8 in a Dual Boot Setup?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, xubuntu, lubuntu, windows-8

I am currently using Lubuntu in tandem with Windows 8 in a dual boot setup. Windows 8 is getting sluggish, so I want to do a clean install of it. In addition, I want to go from Lubuntu to Xubuntu (my laptop is more powerful than I thought). How can I uninstall Lubuntu and reinstall Windows 8, then Install Xubuntu?

Important information:

- No recovery disk, so I have to use the built-in option
- No CD drive, so I have to use a USB
- I know how to install Xubuntu, so I really need to know how to get rid of Lubuntu and reinstall Windows 8

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

First, you must install W8, then Xubuntu.
To download W8, use this [link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=262204), enter the licence number (usually on the back of your computer), and download the *.iso. Then write the W8 iso on a usb-stick, and boot on it. You can install W8 properly.
After installing W8, and only after, install Xubuntu. I imagine you know how to do it.

Comment: Do I need to remove Lubuntu, or does Windows 8 do that for me?

Comment: When you install W8, you can wipe the entire disk. But be careful when making partitions during the W8 pre-installation sequence, if you type "Enter", the installation of W8 starts right away on the partition you just selected. So just create partitions, and when everything is in order, then you select the partition you want W8 on, and you type "Enter". I'm telling you that because I had to reinstall it after selecting a wrong partition.

Comment: I entered my product key, but received the message, "This product key cannot be used to install a retail version of Windows 8"

Comment: I found I can reinstall Windows 8 from the settings? Will this remove Linux?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience with the downloaded file. Concerning the reinstallation of W8, it won't necessarily remove Linux but it will remove grub...